Clock synchronization issue with "current_state_monitor" request and "/joint_states" topic timestamps while controlling UR using "moveit_py"
I have set up a Gazebo simulation with 2 UR manipulators and I'm attempting to control one UR robot using moveit_py. I've followed the necessary configuration steps, including setting use_sim_time to true in Gazebo and all related nodes. However, I'm encountering an issue where 'current_state_monitor.cpp' is not receiving joint_angles with recent timestamps.
Error:
enter image description here
"ur_sort.py":
enter image description here
I've verified that joint states are being published in the correct sim time using "ros2 topic echo /joint_states" and "ros2 topic echo /clock", but it seems that the requested time in error message reflects my PC's total run time instead of the current simulation time step. I tried several ways to set the 'use_sim_time' param to true globally before initializing 'moveit_py' but it's not working out.
